# How to write in a buffer at specific byte in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a char buffer of length 50 bytes. In this buffer, at 20-21 bytes, I want to write a short number, of size 2 bytes, say -1234, specifically at those bytes only? How can I do that?

Comment: could you share some code? your buffer is a dynamically allocated or `char buffer[50]`?

Comment: It is a char* buffer. By the way char* is same as char buffer[], char buffer[] points to address of 1st element in array. So basically they are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks trivial. Not sure whether this is what you want.

```
#include <cstring>

char* pc = ...;
short num = ...;

std::memcpy(pc + 20, &num, 2);
```

Comment: `std::memcpy(pc + 20, &num, sizeof(num))` would be even better.

Comment: One should be careful to understand what they need the buffer to contain. In particular, what is supposed to be the order of the bytes within the buffer. Is it supposed to be big endian, little endian or native endian? This solution works for latter, but not for the former two.